# How to remove , while using Django {% for in %}

Tags: python, django

Trying to stop a comma being used on last item in loop, I want to seperate everything with a , but not the last thing as it is closing with a ] bracket.

```
series: [{
 {% for service in availability.getSortedServices %}
  name: '{{ service }}',
     data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
}, <----------------------------------------------------------------------how can i stop Django/Script stop this for last item on list, i want comma in all items except at end of last 
{% endfor %}
 ]
```

Comment: [`forloop.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: Although you probably shouldn't be generating JSON via template tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you ever so much, can you please give me an example, i am a new coder thank you

Comment: `{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you ever so much, you are the first guy to help me on stackoverflow ever, if i ever become rich and famous :D i won't forget ! thanks a million!

Comment: Note that if you're trying to generate json, you're doing it wrong - Python has a `json` package (in the stdlib) for this.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers   thanks for the reply, i'm acutally just using it to fill highcharts

Comment: @imo json might still be an option to consider as it will garantee your data are well-formed. My 2 cents ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i am a newbie, what is the stdlib ? is it a new file i should put the json in to ?

Comment: @imo sorry, domain slang. "stdlib" is the shortcut for "standard lib" - the set of functions and types that are part of the Python language specs and are distributed with your Python runtime. It consists of the builtin types and functions (those that are always directly available) and a whole set of packages (the "standard libraries") that are installed with your runtime but need to be imported. All this is [document here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).